# Creating a 2d array in flutter / dart

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm brand new to flutter and dart. I've searched google and all I can find is how to make 1d lists in flutter. I need a chart of values.

Specifically I need a row 12 long and a column 31 long filled with ascending numbers

```
1,  32,  63,

2,  33,  64, 

3,  34,  65,  etc....
```

thanks!

Answer (score 23):

```
  int row = 3;
  int col = 4;

  var twoDList = List<List>.generate(row, (i) => List<dynamic>.generate(col, (index) => null, growable: false), growable: false);

  //For fill;
  twoDList[0][1] = "deneme";

  print(twoDList);

// [[null, deneme, null, null], [null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null]]
```

Your 2D list having 3 rows and 4 columns.

Comment: The class 'List' doesn't have an unnamed constructor.

Comment: Could you please share updated code?

Answer (score 7):

Declare and initialize a matrix x having m rows and n columns, containing real numbers.

```
var x = new List.generate(m, (_) => new List(n));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use **smart_arrays_numerics** package...
look at this..
https://pub.dev/packages/smart_arrays_numerics

else you should use nested list.

```
List<List<int>>
```

and create your list with generator

Answer (score 3):

To get exactly what you want, you could use double `List.generate`, i.e.:

```
const cols = 31;
const rows = 12;
final array = List.generate(rows,
    (i) => List.generate(cols + 1, (j) => i + j * cols + 1, growable: false),
    growable: false);

array.forEach((row) {
  print(row);
});
// [1, 32, 63, ...
// [2, 33, 64, ...
// [3, 34, 65, ...
// ...
```

There is also `List.filled`, where you can fill the array with some initial value when created. The following init the 2d array with 0s.

```
final array = List.generate(rows + 1, (i) => List.filled(cols + 1, 0, growable: false), growable: false);
```

Comment: This is actually really smart. Though might have more complexity, the List.filled() is something that comes really handy. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

To `declare` and `initialize` the array `2D` in the `dart`, you can use:

```dart
  List<List<int>> a = 
  [
    [10,   2,  4,  6,  -2],
    [ 1, -16,  6, -2,  -5],
    [ 0,   3, 10, -5,   1],
    [ 0,  -4,  1, 18,   2],
    [ 3,   1,  2,  2, -14],
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a nested collection-`for`:

```dart
const maxRows = 31;
const maxColumns = 12;
var matrix = [
  for (var row = 0; row < maxRows; row += 1)
    [for (var column = 0; column < maxColumns; column += 1)
      1 + row + column * maxRows],
];
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe we can simply create reusable dart code.

```dart
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  var list = createDimensionList(4, 5);
  list[0][0] = 6;
  print(list);
  list[1][0] = 4;
  print(list);
}

List<List<int>> createDimensionList(int rows, int columns,
    {bool growable = false}) {
  final columnLength = List<int>.filled(columns, 0, growable: growable);
  var dataList =
      List.generate(rows, (i) => columnLength.toList(), growable: growable);
  return dataList;
}

//Output
[[6, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[6, 0, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this statement i got this same problem, Got resolved

```
var list1 = List.generate(12,(i) => List.generate(31, (j) =>{Your equation to genearte })));
```

Answer (score 0):

To initialize a 2d matrix filled with 0 :

```
List.generate(numberRows, (_) => List.filled(numberColumns, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  List<dynamic> myArray = nd([12, 31])!;

  print(myArray);
}

List? nd(List<int> dimensions) {
  if (dimensions.isEmpty) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return List.filled(dimensions[0], nd(dimensions.sublist(1)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@vahab

so would I do

```
 final int NROWS = 12, NCOLS = 31;
  List<Float64List> matrix = List(NROWS);   
  for (int i = 0; i < 373; i++) {
    Float64List row = Float64List(NCOLS);

    for (int k = 0; k < NCOLS; k++) {        //I dont know what this does
      row[k] = double.parse("$i.$k");
    }
    matrix[i] = row;
  }
```