# Flutter - how to make an array of objects

Tags: list, flutter, dart

**Edit:**

```
class Transactions {
  final String id;

  final double amount;
  final String date;
  

  const Transactions({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.amount,
    @required this.date,
   
  });}
```

I am trying to ad a transaction to the current month . When the user adds a transaction based on the current moth is I would like to add that transaction to the array,e

so I want to make a list of list of `Transactions`

this is what i have tried :

```
  List<List> _userTransactions = [
            List<Transactions> jan= [];
            List<Transactions> feb= [];
            List<Transactions> mar= [];
            List<Transactions> apr= [];
            List<Transactions> may= [];
            .....
            ];
```

Comment: the currect title is language Dart no Flutter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to initialize a list of hard-coded integers, you can do:

```
var list = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
  ];
```

You can specify the type instead of `var` if you want, it is `List<List<int>>`.

Or, if you want to generate a grid, you can either use a for loop with the `add` function, or use `generate` as per mra9776's answer.

Comment: how would add to the the variable list if it is a dynamic list and there is no hard coded values

Comment: @Chad For this mra9776's answer can help. Or use for loops. So initially, declare an empty list: `List<List<int>> list = [];`, and then inside your loop you can use `list.add(....)`.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:

[already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60432222/7230008)

you might want try this one:

```
final grid = List<List<int>>.generate(
      size, (i) => List<int>.generate(size, (j) => i * size + j));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we have a class with name as **Transactions**
So to make the list of **Transactions** objects we have to create list which is of type  **Transactions**
In the below code part we created a **List**
of type **Transactions** and added objects to them by creating them with the help of new variable

```
List<Transactions> _userTransactions = [
        new Transactions(100, 5000, "4-10-2020"),
        new Transactions(101, 5000, "4-11-2020")
        
        ];
```

for more information about creation of objects and adding them to the **List**

please click the link https://kodeazy.com/flutter-array-userdefined-class-objects/