# Is it possible to create an array of arrays in Dart / Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

What i'm trying to achieve is something similar to this

```
bigArray \[

\[val1, val2, val3\],

\[val1, val2, val3\],

.

.

.

\]
```

basically each inner array has a fixed length of 4, whereas the outer array (bigArray) contains all the inner arrays.

I know this is possible in Java, but i have not been able to recreate it in Flutter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a 2d array in flutter / dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57860596/creating-a-2d-array-in-flutter-dart) --  Also Google `2d array` or `multidimensional array` -- Those terms should help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create an array of arrays in Dart and Flutter. You can do this by creating a list of lists, where each element in the list is another list with a fixed length.

```
List<List<String>> bigArray = [];

// Initialize the inner lists
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 List<String> innerList = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'];
 bigArray.add(innerList);
}

print(bigArray); // Output: [[val1, val2, val3], [val1, val2, val3], [val1, 
                 //val2, val3], [val1, val2, val3], [val1, val2, val3]]
```

Note that in Dart, you don't need to specify the type of the inner lists explicitly when declaring **bigArray**, as the type inference will automatically infer the type based on the initialization. However, if you want to be explicit about the types, you can declare **bigArray** like this:

```
List<List<String>> bigArray = <List<String>>[];
```